# Dual-Boot Ubuntu 18.04/Windows 10 No Room

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning, disk-usage

I am trying to dual boot my Dell Latitude D7270 with Windows and Ubuntu Desktop 18.04. When I enter I look at my storage in settings it says my C: drive has 98GB free (230 GB Total). Yet when I try to partition off the drive in Disk Management (right click on C:, click shrink volume) it only gives me the option to partition ~100MB (see attached image). What's wrong, why can't I partition off a reasonable amount of space?

Comment: You can't use Ubuntu to shrink your Windows partition to prepare for a dual boot configuration.  Since your question is about your Windows drive and since you are having a problem with Windows software, you should ask about this on SuperUser.

Comment: Sometimes you have to temporarily disable system restore, virtual memory and hibernation before you can shrink your partition to the extent you want. If one of the files associated with these is at the end of the drive you cannot shrink it. Search for Windows immovable files for more info.

Comment: Can you attach the image?